# Why am I missing git2.h and how do I get it back?

Tags: python, c, git, linker, libgit2

I am experiencing an odd problem every time I try the set-up of pygit2.  Below is what I run and the error generated.

```
$ python3 setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building '_pygit2' extension
/usr/bin/clang -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk -isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/lib -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.2.3/include/python3.2m -c src/pygit2.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.2/src/pygit2.o
In file included from src/pygit2.c:32:
include/pygit2/error.h:6:10: fatal error: 'git2.h' file not found
#include <git2.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

I think I have successfully installed libgit2 (the build and make finished fine).  Maybe it is a path issue?  I have set LIBGIT2 environment variable to the src directory in the libgit2 folder.  Is that the right place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following step worked for me:

```
brew install libgit2
```

Answer (score 5):

I never installed `libgit2`, but the following might help:

If your distro's repository contains libgit2, I'll advice to remove what you have compiled before and install libgit2 (binaries) and libgit2-dev (headers etc.) packages from the repo. This will place binaries and sources to the right directories.

Otherwise, try symlinking `git2.h` to `/usr/local/include`

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like the `LIBGIT2` variable took (could you show how you set the variable?) as the extra include directive uses `/usr/local/include` (which is the default).

The `LIBGIT2` env var needs to be set to the prefix where the library was installed, typically `/usr` or `/usr/local`. It doesn't look like the library was installed to `/usr/local` as the compiler can't find it, so maybe you need `export LIBGIT2=/usr` before running `setup.py`.

Answer (score 0):

You must be on macOS. Here is how I solved the problem:

```
brew install libgit2
```

If that isn't working because of `Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir`, just run the following command

```
 sudo chown -R $(whoiam) $(brew --prefix)/*
```